# Having trouble posting this data with python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

So I'm trying to post this data with python requests, but there are two problems that i'm having. 
 1. the data isn't posting correctly, and im not sure why. i think im using all the correct headers 
 2. when i try to print out the response.content i get a bunch of weird character output, no real text at all.

Anyone know whats up?

```
import requests
import time
import random
import json
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from python_anticaptcha import AnticaptchaClient, NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask



#sess = requests.Session()
#sess.get("https://slamjamsocialism-drops.com/drops/138")

sess = requests.Session()
link = "https://slamjamsocialism-drops.com/drops/138"
anti_api_key = "my api key"
site_key = "6LfYhz0UAAAAAJFKp28Sg0NnAEIPMfKI1RJSGsdB"

client = AnticaptchaClient(anti_api_key)
task = NoCaptchaTaskProxylessTask(link, site_key)
job = client.createTask(task)
job.join()
captcha = job.get_solution_response()



headers = {

    "authority": "slamjamsocialism-drops.com",
"method": "POST",
"path": "/graphql",
"scheme": "https",
"accept": "*/*",
"accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"authorization": "null",
"content-length": "718",
"content-type": "application/json",
"dnt": "1",
"origin": "https://slamjamsocialism-drops.com",
"referer": "https://slamjamsocialism-drops.com/drops/138",
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36"
}

data = {


   "query":"mutation RequestOrdertMutation($data: OrderRequestInput!) {\n  requestOrder(data: $data)\n}\n",
   "operationName":"RequestOrdertMutation",
   "variables":{
      "data":{
         "firstName":"blah",
         "lastName":"blahblah",
         "email":"testing1236@kornkicks.club",
         "phone":"193482345",
         "country":"840",
         "city":"new cumberland",
         "order":[
            {
               "product":"114",
               "size":"42 ½"
            }
         ],
         "raffle":"138",
         "captcha": captcha

      }
   }
}


response = sess.post('https://slamjamsocialism-drops.com/drops/138', headers=headers, json=data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: What is the response output you receive?

Comment: <0x03><0x17><0x02><0x00>ds

Answer (score 0):

1. Your anti-captcha mechanism may not work.
2. `response.texts` relies on the response header having the correct encoding to decode the content as text, and if it does not, it will try to make a best guess, which may not necessarily be accurate. Set `response.encoding` to the proper encoding after you review the content of `response.content` and determine what encoding it is yourself.

Comment: it looks like the encoding is bytes literal, but how would i set response.encoding to read that properly and output plain english? i am reading that i should set it to utf-8, but wouldn't that be the default anyway? sorry, im pretty new